# Issue with creating data to sqlite database using typeorm ionic 3

Tags: database, sqlite, ionic-framework, ionic3, typeorm

I'm trying to post data into entities using typeorm, and getting this error:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): AlreadyHasActiveConnectionError: Cannot create a new connection named "default", because connection with such name already exist and it now has an active connection session.

I'm connecting to the db in app.component.ts and it works perfectly, then in another page ts file i'm trying to post a data from a form to the entity and this is where my issue is, it keeps telling me that it has already active connection, so what am i supposed to do to post data to the db with typeorm?

TS:

```
import { createConnection } from "ionic-orm";

onAddEquipment() {
let options: ConnectionOptions = {
  autoSchemaSync: true,
  driver: {
    type: "websql",
    database: "bexel"
  },
  entities: [
    Equipments
  ]
  }
   createConnection(options).then(async connection => {
   let equipment = new Equipments();
   equipment = this.equipment;
  await connection.entityManager.persist(equipment);
  console.log("equipment has been saved");
});
}
```

I followed [this](https://github.com/BradyLiles/ionic-orm) documentation.

How can we write the right statement?
Note that it's working without typeorm with native sqlite queries, so no problem with the form it's just i don't know how to write the statement right.

Comment: If I'm using typeorm from a server app, you would connect during application initialization and use the connection to persist the equipment instance as part of an event (user clicked add equipment button).  I wonder if creating the connection done this way in an example because it is an example (versus this is the way to do it).

Comment: actually it worked, review the answer i posted

Answer (score 0):

For anyone suffering from this issue, i added a name property to the options object, and it worked:

```
 let options: ConnectionOptions = {
  autoSchemaSync: true,
  name: 'postEquipments',
  driver: {
    type: "websql",
    database: "bexel"
  },
  entities: [
    Equipments
  ]
  }
```